# How to use WHERE IN in inner join in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables(subjects, student and exam) I'm joining to fetch a student result based on class assigned to a particular teacher.

Let's say a teacher is being assigned two classes(S.S 2 and S.S 3) and from the exam table I only want to select students result based on the class assigned to that teacher.

Here are the tables structures

```
    CREATE TABLE `student` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
      `regiNo` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
      `session` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
      `class` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      `class_group` varchar(26) NOT NULL,
      `firstName` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
      `middleName` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
      `lastName` varchar(60) NOT NULL

     )

INSERT INTO `student` (`id`, `regiNo`, `session`, `class`, `class_group`,  `firstName`, `middleName`, `lastName`) VALUES
(8, 'TS2018007',  '2018', 'Primary One', 'Science',  'ADEWUYI', 'o', 'ODERINDE'),
(9, 'TS2018009',  '2018', 'Primary One', 'N/A',  'Ayodele', 'Jumide', 'Boros')

     CREATE TABLE `exam` (
      `examid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
      `Roll_Number` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
      `sub_id` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
      `mid_term` varchar(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      `count_assessment` varchar(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      `scored` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
      `total_score` varchar(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      `sub_highest` varchar(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      `sub_lowest` varchar(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      `first_term` varchar(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      `second_term` varchar(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      `third_term` varchar(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      `avg_score` varchar(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      `internaltype` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
      `Class` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
      `Year` varchar(4) NOT NULL
    )

INSERT INTO `exam` (`examid`, `Roll_Number`, `sub_id`, `mid_term`, `count_assessment`, `scored`, `total_score`, `sub_highest`, `sub_lowest`, `first_term`, `second_term`, `third_term`, `avg_score`, `internaltype`, `Class`, `Year`) VALUES
(32, 'TS2018007', 'Eng', '54', '20', '50', '134', '80', '70', '45', '12', '43', '45', 'First', 'J.S.S 3', '2019'),
(33, 'TS2018007', 'Agr', '32', '32', '12', '34', '56', '23', '34', '12', '56', '20', 'First', 'J.S.S 3', '2019'),
(34, 'TS2018007', 'math', '54', '20', '45', '12', '45', '34', '34', '12', '12', '23', 'First', 'J.S.S 3', '2019'),
(35, 'TS2018007', 'bio', '54', '27', '23', '23', '12', '12', '45', '55', '12', '45', 'First', 'J.S.S 2', '2019');


    CREATE TABLE `subjects` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
      `subect_code` varchar(55) NOT NULL,
      `subjects` varchar(255) NOT NULL
    )

INSERT INTO `subjects` (`id`, `subect_code`, `subjects`) VALUES
(12, 'Eng', 'English Language'),
(13, 'Agr', 'Agricultural Science'),
(17, 'math', 'Mathematics'),
(20, 'bio', 'Biology'),
(21, 'fur', 'Further Maths'),
(25, 'che', 'Chemistry'),
(26, 'geo', 'Geography');
```

How can I select data from MySQL using **WHERE IN in inner join** in MySQL query?
The query below returned empty result set:

```
SELECT distinct s.regiNo, s.firstName as fname, s.middleName as mname, s.lastName as lname, s.gender, s.class_group, c.subjects,
e.mid_term, e.count_assessment, e.examid, e.scored, e.internaltype, e.Class, e.Year,e.total_score,e.sub_highest,e.sub_lowest,e
.first_term,e.second_term,e.third_term,e.avg_score FROM student s inner join exam e on s.regiNo = e.Roll_Number 
inner join subjects c on e.sub_id = c.subect_code WHERE e.Class IN('S.S 2', 'S.S 3')
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. [See more...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query).

Comment: @TrebuchetMS, what other example do I need to give? What I provided is just a MySQL query to my actual question.

Comment: @wealthouseinfo Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query for SQL related questions and provide the necessary information like `CREATE TABLE` statements and example data.

Comment: @wealthouseinfo We have no knowledge of what your database, tables, and columns are implemented. That's part of what a minimal, complete, and verifiable example (mcve) implies. Sorry if I wasn't clear on that one but the links do elaborate. E.g. if you got an error, show us the error. If it doesn't work as expected (empty result set) show what _you __do___ expect (along with a mcve). It's difficult to try to mentally parse the sql query. Even if we feed it to a workbench or terminal, the tables will be undefined.

Comment: "what other example do I need to give? What I provided is just a MySQL query to my actual question" Topicstarter SQL is a declaratief laugauge which means  basic elements are not assignments, but descriptions that are compiled into more complex descriptions. What basically means without table stuctures and data example we don't know what the results from a query are we can only make "educated guesses" why your query does not give the correct results.. Thats why we need table structures and example data like @TrebuchetMS suggested.

Comment: @TrebuchetMS, I have updated my question. Is that ok now?

Comment: @wealthouseinfo Well, like we've mentioned previously, we'll also be looking for data samples (e.g. 2-5 rows per table that produce a minimal result) and your expected result. You could also go ahead and try out [Steven's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54852315/10239789) below to debug your query -- a crucial skill to acquire sooner or later.

Comment: Incidentally, things like `first_term, second_term, third_term` can be indicative of poor design. You might consider splitting those out to a single column in a separate table.

Answer (score 0):

To debug this:

- remove the joins, remove joined rows from select, and confirm results
- add one join, make it a `left join`, and confirm results
- change `left join` to `inner join` and confirm results
- Do the previous 2 steps with your other join.

The `inner joins` can end up excluding all rows, especially with 2 of them.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, guys. I discovered I was the one making mistakes. The specified values in my IN clause did not match any value in the table row which was the reason for it returning null values.

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.regiNo, 
s.firstName as fname, 
s.middleName as mname, 
s.lastName as lname, 
s.gender, 
s.class_group, 
c.subjects, 
e.mid_term, 
e.count_assessment, 
e.examid, 
e.scored, 
e.internaltype, 
e.Class, 
e.Year,
e.total_score,
e.sub_highest,
e.sub_lowest,
e .first_term,
e.second_term,
e.third_term,
e.avg_score 
FROM student s 
INNER JOIN exam e 
ON s.regiNo = e.Roll_Number 
INNER JOIN subjects c ON 
e.sub_id = c.subect_code 
WHERE e.Class IN('J.S.S 3','J.S.S 2') 
GROUP BY
s.regiNo, 
s.firstName, 
s.middleName, 
s.lastName, 
s.gender, 
s.class_group, 
c.subjects, 
e.mid_term, 
e.count_assessment, 
e.examid, 
e.scored, 
e.internaltype, 
e.Class, 
e.Year,
e.total_score,
e.sub_highest,
e.sub_lowest, 
e.first_term,
e.second_term,
e.third_term,
e.avg_score
```